# Merging multiple columns into one creating one row for each column in mysql

Tags: mysql, unpivot

I have a mysql table with the following columns

```
SNP
Probe
Genotype_00
Mean_00
Std_00
Genotype_01
Mean_01
Std_01
Genotype_11
Mean_11
Std_11
```

I would like the table to have the following columns:

```
SNP
Probe
Genotype
Mean 
Std
```

where for each pair (SNP,Probe) I have three rows, one corresponding to each genotype.

For example the row

```
rs1 probe1 AA 5.6 0.3 AG 4.3 0.2 GG 3.4 0.1
```

should be transformed into

```
rs1 probe1 AA 5.6 0.3
rs1 probe1 AG 4.3 0.2
rs1 probe1 GG 3.4 0.1
```

Can anyone help me finding a way to do this?
Thanks a lot in advance, any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Rossella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Table with follow columns.

```
SNP
Probe
Genotype
Mean 
Std
```

Then execute these SQL statements one by one

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT SNP, Probe, Genotype_00, Mean_00, Std_00
FROM old_table

INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT SNP, Probe, Genotype_01, Mean_00, Std_01
FROM old_table


INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT SNP, Probe, Genotype_11, Mean_00, Std_11
FROM old_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply create a new table with SNP Probe Genotype Mean Std, then use

```
insert into NEWTABLE
select SNP, Probe, Genotype_00, Mean_00, Std_00
from old table
```

Then change 00 to 01 and 11, run the queries again.

However, as the snp pairs won't be next to each other, you may want to create indices.